# Why is my internet faster than WLAN?

Tags: windows-7, windows, wireless-networking, internet, internet-connection

Why is my internet connection (with a wireless router) faster than my wireless LAN connection?

The former is normally ~2 MB/s (I get ~3 MB/s sometimes too), but the latter just doesn't go above a few hundred KB/s (around 200-ish). It's pretty much useless.

When I turn *off* encryption, I can get the WLAN speed to go higher to 1 MB/s or so, but of course that doesn't affect my internet speed, which also uses encryption. And obviously it's not something I want to do.

How can this be? How do people get multiple-MB/s wireless networks?

(Router: Netgear WNR1000v2-VC)

Comment: What encryption(s) are you using?

Comment: @TomWijsman: WPA2/AES, but I've also tried other combinations. WEP is generally faster than WPA2, and no encryption is much faster than both -- but for the internet connection, it makes no difference.

Comment: What type of wireless network are you using? 802.11a/b/g/n? What current rate does the adapter report?

Comment: @TomWijsman: I believe I've connected using Wireless N, but I'm not 100% positive. I do believe I've tried putting my router into G-only mode (54 Mbps), which exhibits the same problem. But I'll try it again later today and post here if I'm mistaken, since that was a long time ago. Either way, I don't see why it makes a difference for the internet vs. WLAN, though...

Comment: The problem could be interference from other 2.4 Ghz sources.  See here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electromagnetic_interference_at_2.4_GHz

Comment: @bwall: Why would the internet get 3 MB/s with no problem, then? (I've tried changing the channel, btw, with no effect.)

Comment: Ah, I misunderstood what you were doing on the LAN.  How are you measuring WLAN speed?  What are the details of the two machines data is being transferred between?

Comment: @bwall: Both machines are Windows 7, but I *think* (though I'm not sure) I've tried with XP on both as well, with the same results. I'm measuring WLAN speed by copying a 4-GB file around, and it averages around 300 KB/s or so, according to the file copy dialog. On the other hand, Free Download Manager can download Chromium in literally ~10 seconds (and it's > 30 MB)... and yet it takes me *much* longer to copy the same file across WLAN. (I don't believe my measurements are incorrect. :P)

Comment: Could be Remote Differential Compression.  Here's a link to an article about this.  It was a big problem on Vista, and is still there on Windows 7.  There are several other tips also.  I'll post it as an answer also.  Try some of these tips and see if they make a difference: http://www.sysprobs.com/windows-7-network-slow

Comment: @bwall: It's not Remote Differential Compression; I've tried turning it off. It's not even a Windows 7-specific issue -- it happens on XP too.

Answer (score 0):

If the WLAN speed problem is file copying between Windows 7 machines, there are several known issues that could be causing the problems.  Windows 7 introduces all kinds of overhead to network file sharing.  Here are some tips which might improve the speed:

http://www.sysprobs.com/windows-7-network-slow

For what it's worth, there are still some lingering problems with Windows 7 file sharing speed covered in this very lengthy thread over at Microsoft Technet Forums:

http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/w7itproperf/thread/4537c7b6-9761-41c5-8b47-0ecb831c8575

Answer (score 0):

It's worth noting that *unencrypted*, *ad-hoc* (i.e. router-less) connections can reach the same speed.

The cause seems to be encryption, though I can't make sense of why it would cause such a drastic slowdown.